# Can't mass-assign protected attributes:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to submit a form with multiple instances of a class called Boxscore and I keep getting an error saying class "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: 0, 1"

My Form:

```
  <%= form_for([@boxscore]) do |x| %>
<% 2.times do |i| %>
    <%= fields_for 'boxscores', Boxscore.new, :index => i do |f| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :game_id %><br />
        <%= f.number_field :game_id %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :player_id, "Choose a player" %>
        <%= f.select :player_id, Player.all.map{|t| [t.name, t.id]}, 
                 { :include_blank => true } %>
        </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :points %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :points %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :rebounds %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :rebounds %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :assists %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :assists %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :blocks %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :blocks %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :steals %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :steals %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :turnovers %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :turnovers %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :fgattempted %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :fgattempted %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :fgmade %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :fgmade %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :threepointattempted %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :threepointattempted %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :threepointmade %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :threepointmade %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>       
<div class="actions">
    <%= x.submit %>
</div>
 <% end %>
```

My model:

```
 class Boxscore < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :boxscore_id, :assists, :blocks, :fgattempted, :fgmade, :game_id, :player_id, :points, :rebounds, :steals, :threepointattempted, :threepointmade, :turnovers

  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :player
end
```

My controller:

```
def create
  @boxscore = Boxscore.new(params[:boxscores])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @boxscore.save
      format.html { redirect_to @boxscore, notice: 'Boxscore was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @boxscore, status: :created, location: @boxscore }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @boxscore.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

My params hash when creating a boxscore:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"JJI3di/InpEp4S6HktQWgVfyvk296M7upgQIQRPzJp8=", "boxscores"=>{"0"=>{"game_id"=>"2", "player_id"=>"1", "points"=>"11", "rebounds"=>"22", "assists"=>"11", "blocks"=>"11", "steals"=>"111", "turnovers"=>"22", "fgattempted"=>"3", "fgmade"=>"2", "threepointattempted"=>"11", "threepointmade"=>"22"}, "1"=>{"game_id"=>"2", "player_id"=>"3", "points"=>"3", "rebounds"=>"4", "assists"=>"3", "blocks"=>"55", "steals"=>"4", "turnovers"=>"3", "fgattempted"=>"3", "fgmade"=>"3", "threepointattempted"=>"3", "threepointmade"=>"3"}}, "commit"=>"Create Boxscore", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"boxscores"}
```

Comment: Can you update the post to show a copy of the `params` hash as it's submitted with the post?

Comment: Hi Kevin- I just updated the post with the bosxscore create params hash. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
@boxscore = Boxscore.new(params[:boxscores])
```

The problems is here. `params[:boxscores]` contains two boxscores. And you're trying to create one. Should be something like this:

```
params[:boxscores].each do |k, bs|
  @boxscore = Boxscore.new(bs)
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Hi Sergio- would you be able to advise what I would need to add to save both boxscores?

Comment: Given my answer and Kevin's, what exactly are asking? To give you working code?

Comment: my understanding of the above is that I am iterating through the key value pairs of the :boxscores object and then creating a new instance for each value (bs)? That seems like it would work to me but I am completely new to this so obviously missing something. Thanks again.

Comment: thank you, would you be able to point me in the right direction for troubleshooting, such as what I should read up on to get some direction? With the above code it saves the 2nd boxscore object in the hash but not the first object...

Comment: @BlaneCordes: I usually use a lot of debug printing.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you've posted the params, it makes the problem a bit clearer.

You can see below that you're posting **2** boxscore records here from your form -- they are identified in the params hash as '0' and '1', which are the two attributes that ActiveRecord is telling you it's having problems with.

The solution is to either do, as Sergio suggests and process them like:

```
params[:boxscores].each do |k, bs|
  @boxscore = Boxscore.new(bs)
  # ...
end
```

Or process them individually as two seperate records like this:

```
  @boxscore1 = Boxscore.new(params[:boxscores][0])
  @boxscore2 = Boxscore.new(params[:boxscores][1])
```

In general, when you're having weird issues processing form postings, the params hash will help you understand what's happening.

Your params hash in a cleaner, JSON'd format:

```
{
  "utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"JJI3di/InpEp4S6HktQWgVfyvk296M7upgQIQRPzJp8=",
  "boxscores"=>{
    "0"=>{
        "game_id"=>"2",
        "player_id"=>"1",
        "points"=>"11",
        "rebounds"=>"22",
        "assists"=>"11",
        "blocks"=>"11",
        "steals"=>"111",
        "turnovers"=>"22",
        "fgattempted"=>"3",
        "fgmade"=>"2",
        "threepointattempted"=>"11",
        "threepointmade"=>"22"
    },
    "1"=>{
        "game_id"=>"2",
        "player_id"=>"3",
        "points"=>"3",
        "rebounds"=>"4",
        "assists"=>"3",
        "blocks"=>"55",
        "steals"=>"4",
        "turnovers"=>"3",
        "fgattempted"=>"3",
        "fgmade"=>"3",
        "threepointattempted"=>"3",
        "threepointmade"=>"3"
    }
  },
  "commit"=>"Create Boxscore",
  "action"=>"create",
  "controller"=>"boxscores" 
}
```